# Hiding CSS overlay

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on an app that seems to be using CSS overlays. I have a basic understanding of CSS but not an expert.

In the style.css I see two classes:

```
.modal-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 15000;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out; }

.modal-wrapper.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden; }
```

I'm using this in a React app and I need help with closing the overlay.

I simply render a component and set its isShown property to true and I'm able to open up the overlay.

However, I'm not sure about how to close it. Even if I set the isShown value to false in my redux store, the overlay still sits there.

I'd appreciate some help with closing the overlay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it helps!

```
.modal-wrapper.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but would like a bit more clarification. I think the existing modal-wrapper.hide does the trick but I'm not sure how to invoke it.

Comment: $('.modal-wrapper').addClass('hide'); on close event

Comment: Thank you. I get the idea. Now I need to figure out how to do this in React. Because everything is in the virtual DOM, I can't use jQuery.

Comment: You need to know close event, you may use native javascript to add class

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting your z-index to -1 or something lower, as the overlay will sit-on-top of other elements.

```
.modal-wrapper.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

HTML

```
<div class="modal-wrapper"></div>
<div class="modal-wrapper hide"></div>
```

CSS

```
.modal-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 15000;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.2s ease-in-out; }

.modal-wrapper.hide {
     opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    height: 20px;
    }

  .modal-wrapper.hide:after, .modal-wrapper.hide:before {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translatex(-1px) rotate(45deg);
}
.modal-wrapper.hide:before{
     transform: translatex(0) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sonymathew/b8Lbbz5p/)